# Anyone using Knockoutjs with asp.net-mvc in anger?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-3.0, knockout.js

I find it very interesting and have a prototype working based on Steve's [mvc sample](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/) and [another small sample](http://pastie.org/1227240) from this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs/browse_thread/thread/14bddd15ceee25f4).  Using [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) to deserialize within the post action as I couldn't figure how to downgrade his FromJsonAttribute from .net 4 to .net 3.5, which I'm running in this case.

Wanted to know if anyone had put the [Knockoutjs JavaScript library](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) into production with asp.net-mvc and found any major issues?

Comment: can you update that pastie link? I would like a wee nosey at your Knockoutjs sample.

Comment: I've had it in production for 3 months now without had any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use an another approach in my ASP MVC projects. I do AJAX calls passing individual elements instead of arrays every time an underlying model is modified, and Knockout updates UI.

Comment: I've ended up using a similar smaller posting.  it works quite well, making it autosave effectively.  is this what you are doing, or pick that up wrong?

Comment: Yes, I mean the same. :)